# android recursively list the files in sd card

Tags: android, file-listing

I want to search for a particular file in my sd card . So i am trying to list complete files and search for the pattern. Please see code below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File(root_sd);
    listfiles( new File(root_sd));

}

public void listfiles(File file) {

    //file = new File(path);
    // file = new File( root_sd ) ;
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    Log.i("DIR", "PATH" +file.getPath());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        // myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        File temp_file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(),list[i].getName());
        Log.i("DIR", "PATH" +temp_file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (temp_file.isFile() && temp_file.listFiles() != null) {
            Log.i("inside", "call fn");
            listfiles(temp_file);

        } else {
            if (list[i].getName().toLowerCase().contains("pattern1"))
                Log.i("File", i + list[i].getName());
            if (list[i].getName().toLowerCase().contains("pattern2"))
                Log.i("File", i + list[i].getName());

        }
    }
```

Here  only first level of search is happening . This condition `if (temp_file.isFile() && temp_file.listFiles() != null)`

is always returning false and thus recursive call not happening. 
Please help me to fix it. Thanks for your answer and time.

Comment: `.isDirectory()` instead of `isFile()`? When it is a file than the list has to be `null`. Only directories can be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the `temp_file.isFile()` returns true then it means it is a file and hence `temp_file.listFiles()` automatically becomes null thus making your entire statement false. Thus your combined statement returns a false always. What you need is a `||` in place of `&&`.

Comment: I need to keep only one condition that listFiles != null